# execute the javascript code and check radiobutton based on $id=$_GET['id']; when page is load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

Please help me some one ...
when the page is load , if the **$Id=pack** radiobutton **pack** as to  checked and **DIV PACK Display:Block;**

if the **$id =ind** , then radiobutton ind as to  checked and **DIV ind Display:Block;**

```
<?PHP
    $id=$_GET['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>

        <label>Package</label>
        <input type="radio" name="package" value="pack"  
                <?php if($id=='pack') 
                    { 
                        echo"checked"; 
                        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                        echo"document.getElementById(\"package\").style.display=\"block\"";
                        echo"</script>";
                     } ?> 
         >

        <label>Individual</label>
        <input type="radio" name="package" value="ind" 
                 <?php if($id=='ind') 
                     {
                       echo"checked"; 
                       echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                       echo"document.getElementById(\"individual\").style.display=\"block\"";
                       echo"</script>";
                      } ?> 
         >

        <div id="package" style=" display:none; height:100px; background-color:#a00; color:#fff;">
            Display this div if PACKAGE is checked
        </div>

        <div id="individual"  style=" display:none; height:100px; background-color:#a00; color:#fff;">
            Display this div if INDIVIDUAL is checked
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you dont need js for that, you could just do like,
create css class

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block
}
```

and in php file

```
$packChecked = ($id == "pack") ? "checked='checked'" : "";
$indChecked = ($id == "ind") ? "checked='checked'" : "";
$packClass = ($id == "pack") ? "show" : "hide";
$indClass = ($id == "ind") ? "show" : "hide";
then apply, like:
<input type="radio" name="package" value="pack" <?php echo $packChecked; ?> />
<div id="package" class="<?php echo $packClass; ?>">
...
</div>
//similarly for another radio button
```

Comment: why downvote.. any reason.. n its better to comment for downvote rather than negating n running away..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
    $id=$_GET['id'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <body>

        <label>Package</label>
        <input type="radio" name="package" value="pack"  >



        <label>Individual</label>
        <input type="radio" name="package" value="ind"   >



        <div id="package" style=" display:none; height:100px; background-color:#a00; color:#fff;">
            Display this div if PACKAGE is checked
        </div>

        <div id="individual"  style=" display:none; height:100px; background-color:#a00; color:#fff;">
            Display this div if INDIVIDUAL is checked
        </div>
                        <?php if($id=='pack') 
                    { 
                        echo"checked"; 
                        echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                        echo"document.getElementById(\"package\").style.display=\"block\"";
                        echo"</script>";
                     } ?> 
                                      <?php if($id=='ind') 
                     {
                       echo"checked"; 
                       echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">";
                       echo"document.getElementById(\"individual\").style.display=\"block\"";
                       echo"</script>";
                      } ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks... the script is okay, but how can u checked the radiobutton ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the whole "click radio show/hide that div" thing on the client side with a bit of CSS and jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
        var showId = $(this).val() === 'pack' ? 'package' : 'individual';
        var hideId = (showId === 'package') ? 'individual' : 'package';
        $('#' + showId).show();
        $('#' + hideId).hide();
    });
});
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nV8dF/)

Instead of hide() and show() you can also use toggle() or toggleClass() in combination with a 'show' or 'hide' CSS class as Sudhir pointed out.

A solution like this keeps your code a bit cleaner imho :)

Comment: Thanks , @Lave Loos  , what i want is when the page is load the radiobutton has to be checked and div has to be Display ,  this functon has to be work onload itself not in onchange

Comment: Oh ok, misunderstood you there. In that case you can use Sudhirs answer. You could still use my code for client side though :) Happy coding!